# Append parameter to URL on page exit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get parameter values from the url and re-direct if the param=1

for example: If my web page url is www.example.com&param=1 then all the links in a div **image-header** on this page should have this parameter appended at the end of the url on exit

```
<div id="image-header" >
<a href="www.example.com"></a>
<a href="www.example.com"></a>
<a href="www.example.com"></a>
</div>
```

So, if param=1 and if I click on example.com, then the clicked url should go to www.example.com&param=1 . Is this possible in JavaScript?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why don't you do it server side ?

Comment: You mean www.example.com?param=1

Comment: i assume you use that param on serverside you should probably also add it on serverside so it's easy to maintain

Comment: If I come to a webpage example1 with a param in the URL - www.example1.com&param1 and click on any other link on that web page(say example2), I will go to clicked page with the param value www.example2.com&param1. The solution below by stefan works  for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to bind a click event to all a elements and prevent default, then set window.location to the href attribute of a plus your parameters.

```
<div id="image-header" >
    <a href="http://www.google.com">example 1</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">example 2</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">example 3</a>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location = $(this).attr('href')+location.search;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: your answer does not show how to get the param from URL, also you can simply update the attribute, no need to preventDefault

Comment: @Huangism `location.search` gets all parameters from the url, he also asked for it onclick that is why I preventDefault, updating every A elements attributes would require a loop which could be costly on a large page.

Comment: nvm it was updated, you don't need to preventDefault or set new location, you can just do $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + location.search); and it will take the user to the updated url. I have always thought this might create a racing condition but I use it here at work and it has not gone wrong yet

Comment: @Huangism but will it work on the dark IE and his old minions ? Just for that I would be tempted to keep the prevent default

Comment: We support IE 7 and up and it has no issues that I know of. As for IE 6 I will first shoot myself then see if there are any issues